# Spring - @Autowired bean from @Configuration is null

Tags: spring, autowired, spring-config

I define a bean in a configuration class. I would like to autowire this bean in a component. However, the property stays null. E.g.:

Appconfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SomeType someObject() {
        return new SomeType();
    }
}
```

AppComponent.java

```
@Component
public class AppComponent {

    @Autowired
    private SomeType someObject;  // TODO why null?

    public AppComponent() {  // note: passing a SomeType constructor argument works
        System.out.println(someObject);
    }
}
```

How can I autowire a bean defined in a configuration class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you missing a fundamental detail that properties are injected after a bean is created? Have you tried access your property after a bean is fully initialized?

**Update:**
I've reworked your example a little to demonstrate you the difference:

```
@Test
public void initializationTest() {
    try (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
                 new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext()) {
        context.register(AppConfiguration.class, AppComponent.class);
        context.refresh();
    }
}

@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SomeType someObject() {
        return new SomeType();
    }
}


@Component
public class AppComponent {

    @Autowired
    private SomeType someObject;

    public AppComponent() {
        // Here properties are not yet injected by Spring IoC container
        System.out.println(someObject); // Obviously prints null
    }

    /**
     * Method is invoked after a bean is initialized and all its properties are being set.
     */
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        System.out.println(someObject); // Prints SomeType@6b419da
    }
}

public class SomeType {
}
```

So basically bean lifecycle consists of the following steps:

1. Bean instance is created
2. Bean properties are set
3. In case bean implements `Aware` interfaces - those implemented methods are invoked
4. `BeanPostProcessor#postProcessBeforeInitialization` methods of custom bean post-processors are invoked
5. Initialization callbacks are invoked in the following order:
5.1. `@PostConstruct` method is invoked
5.2. `InitializingBean#afterPropertiesSet()` method is invoked
5.3. `@Bean#initMethod()` method is invoked
**Bean is fully initialized now.**
6. `BeanPostProcessor#postProcessAfterInitialization` methods of custom post-processors are invoked
are invoked.
7. Destruction callbacks are invoked in the following order:
7.1. `@PreDestroy` method is invoked
7.2. `DisposableBean#destroy()` method is invoked
7.3. `@Bean#destroyMethod` method is invoked